# How much disk space does SO take up?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, server

Just out of personal curiosity, how much disk space on the server does Stack Overflow take up? I'm guessing it's a lot, but I can't know for sure.

Comment: Couldn't possibly be more than around 640KB.

Comment: No no no, that's the RAM needed to run it.

Comment: I don't see this [listed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369), but you might find more information in the sources it cites.  In particular, you might note that SO is *several* servers. :)

Comment: Well, each vote takes up a little more space in the database, so let's just keep upvoting this post until it runs out of disk space

Comment: The size of the datadump may serve as an approximation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was 12gigs compressed a few months ago, probably up to about 15gigs compressed (50 gigs uncompressed)

It is not a particularly huge database, most of the storage we have is taken up by history and indexes. Fitting most of our data in RAM is one of the reasons our performance is so awesome (that and Jeff's amazing wheel of blame).

When you look at perfmon: SQL server page life expectancy is massive, we barely go to disk.

Comment: Kudos to you Sam Saffron, creator of Discourse :) I see size is looked upon heavily and that's a good thing!

Answer (score 6):

This is an ever increasing number, so no answer would be correct for long. However, you can use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) to estimate the number. The following was accurate in the second half of August 2014.

*The Data Explorer does not include the 15% of posts that are deleted (which stays in the real database) or all of the post history, so the actual database size is much higher. Thanks to to [Weapon of Choice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/weapon-of-choice) for this [information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70078/how-much-disk-space-does-so-take-up/238451#comment781479_238455).*

- [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219990/get-size-of-database-tables) can be used to find the **size of the database tables alone** (without indexes), which currently is **`140 GB`**.
- [`sp_spaceused` on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219994/sp-spaceused) can be to find the **database size including indexes**, which currently is `186,567 MB / 1024 =`**`182 GB`**.

Comment: SEDE does not contain deleted posts and much of voting and review histories. Around 15% of posts are deleted, but they remain in the database.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Thank you, that is a good point. I updated my answer to include it.